# Is it nessessary to verify an uploaded file via checksum?

Tags: c#, upload, dotnet-httpclient, sha256, checksum

Lets say, I upload really important files such a contracts via an API with `HttpClient` in .Net with the following code:

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    foreach (FileInfo fi in inputFiles)
    {
        content.Add(CreateFileContent(fi));
    }
    AwaitRateLimit();
    var response = await _Client.PostAsync("upload/", content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    // deserialize
    string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    ClientResponse.Response decodedResponse = 
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClientResponse.Response>(responseJson);
}
```

```
private StreamContent CreateFileContent(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileInfo.OpenRead());
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "\"file\"",
        FileName = "\"" + fileInfo.Name + "\""
    };
    return fileContent;
}
```

Currently I do the following:

1. Send multiple files via post in one request
2. Download each file into ram, build sha256checksum of it and compare it against local files sha256checksum

step 1 is really quick (~a couple of seconds) for a large quantity of files
step 2 takes at least 15 minutes, because each file can only be downloaded individually.

Therefore I would know if you consider step 2 nessesary or if the `HttpClient` will handle that automatically.

Comment: No, it won't automatically download after uploading.

Comment: I thought it may automatically selnd verify checksums. sad.